# c# datagridview how to pass value using txtbox in other form

Tags: c#, forms

- form1  i got a gui buttons to pick
- form2 is my datagridview
- form3 is where i input the name surname and mi
- my code for form1 is form2.show
- on my form2 is form3.show
- i have a code in form3 that uses a counter to input in datagridView1

> ```
>  private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>             {
>                 int counter = 0;
>                 if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1)
>                 {
>                     while (counter != dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
>                     {
>                     if (dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells[0].Value.ToString() ==txtName.Text)
>                     {
>                         MessageBox.Show("name already exist");
>                         return;
>                     }
>                     counter++;
>                 }
>             }
> if (txtName.Text == "")
>             {
>                 MessageBox.Show("name field should not be empty");
>                 return;
>             }
> else
>             {
>                 dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txtName.Text);
>             }
> ```

- my problem is that form3 dont recognize dataGridView1 how do i get the value of textbox in form3 into datagridview in form2.

Comment: Firstly, does it make sense to call `Show` rather than `ShowDialog` for `form3`?  Normally, you would open the dialogue, the user enters data, the dialogue closes and the data is then used in the caller, i.e. `form2` in this case.  Is that how it should work in your case?

Comment: how do u do that? sorry currently new at c#

Comment: I asked a question and I asked it for a reason.  Please provide an answer.  Once I have that information I will be able to advise you on how to proceed.

Comment: Yes that is how it should work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pass the `Reference of DataGridView` to `form 3`.

**Step 1:** Create Over-loaded Constructor of `form3`.

```
DataGridView dg;

 public Form3(ref DataGridView dgv)
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    dg=dgv;
 }
```

**Step 2:** From Form2, how to call, Pass `form2 datagridview reference` in `form3 constructor`...

```
form3 frm = new form3(ref datagridview1);
frm.show();
```

**Step 3:** Your Form3 Code..

```
     private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        int counter = 0;
        if (dg.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
             while (counter != dg.Rows.Count - 1)
             {
                 if (dg.Rows[counter].Cells[0].Value.ToString() ==txtName.Text)
                 {
                      MessageBox.Show("name already exist");
                      return;
                  }
                  counter++;
             }
        }
        if (txtName.Text == "")
        {
             MessageBox.Show("name field should not be empty");
             return;
        }
        else
        {
            dg.Rows.Add(txtName.Text);
        }
   }
```

Comment: That works but it's a bad idea because it couples the two forms far more tightly than is necessary.  The dialogue that gathers the data should have to care about how the data gets used afterwards.  If you decided that you wanted to do something else with the data other than put it in a grid then you'd have to make significant changes to both forms.  If you let the dialogue simply expose the data and let the caller decide how it gets used, a change like that would have exactly zero effect on the dialogue, which is how it should be.

Comment: Also, what reason is there for passing the grid by reference to the dialogue?  Are you assigning a different object tot hat parameter inside the constructor?  That's the only valid reason for declaring that parameter `ref` and you're not doing that, so don't use `ref`.

Comment: Also, why would you overload the constructor?  If you're going to pass the grid in like that then that's going to be the ONLY constructor.  If you still have a constructor with no parameters then what happens if that gets used?  `NullReferenceException` is what.

Comment: i will review later thnx i need to present now or i will get a failing grade before our defence.

Answer (score 0):

If the dialogue is being opened, data entered and then the dialogue is closed, you shouldn't be calling `Show` at all.  You should be calling `ShowDialog` instead, which displays the form as a modal dialogue.  In that case, the caller can pass data into the dialogue by setting properties or passing method arguments before displaying the dialogue and then get data back out by getting properties or getting method return values.  It's then up to the caller to do what it wants with the data, which means that your `form2` can populate its own grid.

E.g.

```
using (var dialogue = new Form3())
{
    // Pass data in as required.
    dialogue.SomeProperty = someValue;

    // Display the dialogue...
    if (dialogue.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // ...and get data out if the user clicks OK.
        someOtherValue = dialogue.SomeOtherProperty;

        // Use data here.
    }
}
```

It's up to you to define the appropriate members in the dialogue form to expose the data you want.

Comment: For a more complete explanation, check this out: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html.  I'd recommend reading parts 1 and 2 first but part 3 is the most important.

Comment: any tutorial how to use dialog? nvm u  posted earlier than me

Comment: thnx but i just have 20mins to present my work i will read your blog after , thnx for helping.